# Issues with proftpd on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I'm in the process of setting up a new server running Ubuntu 9.10 and I need to be able to access my web directory via FTP.  I've installed proftpd, opened up port 21 and made sure it was up and running.  Everything seems good, but when I try to connect via FTP from my personal computer to the server it times out each time.  I've been stuck on this issue for a while now and I would appreciate any help.  Any ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to connect to the server's IP from the server itself?

Please post output of `netstat -na | grep :21` to make sure it is, indeed, listening on the right IP address.

Comment: I did that and it says tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:21 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN   I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: this is a good sign. This means that it is listening on all available IP addresses. 

Are you running `iptables` on that server? If so, please explain your setup. Is there a NAT?

Comment: Yes, I am running iptables. I think this might be where the problem is... I don't know if I opened port 21 correctly.  Any advice on how I can do that correctly?

Comment: please posts output of  `iptables -vnL | grep 21`

Comment: I got it working.  YOu were spot on about the iptables. Thanks!